# How to set a ContentOffset of Scrollview When i Swipe image i got its Image Offset into Scrollview in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

i am new in `iOS Development`.
 i make an app that Contain One `UIImageview` and One `UIScrollView`.
Here `UIScrollview` is Contain My All array Image and imageview Contain Only One Image when Swipe  On `UIImageview` then it Contain Next image From Array
 it is Working Fine But now i want to When Swipe Imageview then Also I Scrollview Center i want to Show Which Image in UISCrollview For this I set ContentOffSet For Scrollview then it is not Working as i want when my array Contain More image.
Like as when my Array Contain 100 image and i Swipe 90th Index image then My Scrollview ContentOffSet Show only 89th Index image and then Not Swipe my Scrollview.
My Code For this like as

```
    for(int index=0; index < [self.imagesa count]; index++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *image=[dict valueForKey:@"link”];
    smallImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [smallImage setTag:index];
    smallImage.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.width);
    smallImage.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 0, 50, 50);
    [smallImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
        CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width*[self.imagesa count], self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:smallImage];
    xOffset += 60;
}
```

and Swipe left Code is

```
-(void)slideToLeftWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
NSLog(@"swipe left");
NSLog(@"index %d",indexes);
if(indexes < [self.imagesa count]-1)
{
    indexes++;
    NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:indexes];
    NSString *imagelink=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
    NSLog(@"imageLink %@",imagelink);
    [self.bigImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagelink]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    [self.bigScrollview addSubview:self.bigImage];
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(60+(indexes*smallImage.frame.size.width), 0) animated:YES];
}
```

}

I got a code to Swipe left to Arrange Scrollview ContentOffset As i want

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake((indexes*self.scrollView.frame.size.width/5),0) animated:YES];
```

it is working as i want but now i want to Swipe Right to set contentOffset as Respective to Swipe Left Please Give me Solution now Only For Swipe Right.

Comment: are you using paging scrollview?

Comment: you dont need a gestureRecognizer to wipe left or right if you are using a paging controller and proper scrollview delegates

Comment: Sorry Bro but i got Solution Right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an Answer for Both Like as

For Swipe Left

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake((indexes*self.scrollView.frame.size.width/5)-60,0) animated:YES];
```

And For Swipe Right

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake((indexes*smallImage.frame.size.width),0) animated:YES];
```